# Question about periodic points in shift spaces

Tags: dynamical-systems, coding-theory, regular-language

Let $A$ be a finite set endowed with the discrete topology. Then, the pair $(A^{\mathbb{Z}}, \sigma)$ is said to be the full shift over the alphabet $A$ where $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is endowed with the product topology and $\sigma:A^{\mathbb{Z}} \to A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the shift map $\left((x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mapsto (x_{i+1})_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}\right)$. A shift space $X$ over the alphabet $A$ is a closed subset of $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ invariant by the shift map. A point $x \in X$ is said to be periodic if $\sigma^n(x)=x$ for some posite integer $n$.

I am trying, with no success so far, to construct a shift space $X$ with no periodic points. But I couldn't also prove that there is not such a shift space. So that bring my question: is there a shift space over a finite alphabet with no periodic points?
If yes, could you give me an example?
If not, could you give me some hints on how to prove that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an example of a point that is not periodic? I didn't manage to find one, so may be I missed something and such an example would clarify things to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer comes years later, you can define a metric on double-sided shift space like following,

$d(x,y) = (1/2)^{n(x,y)}$ where $n(x,y)=min(|m|:x_m \neq y_m, m\in \mathbb{Z} )-1$

Now you can see, for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can define your periodic sequence y such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ where x in any element of your shift space and y is the periodic sequence with m common element.

It shows that periodic points are dense in shift spaces.

Comment: This assumes that $X$ contains that point $y$, but doesn't demonstrate it.